# AngularJS Intellisense not working Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

When coding in AngularJS, I don't seem to get intellisense in html files for calling variables defined in my controllers.

E.g. If I have:

```
$scope.username = "test-user";
```

in my controller, when I go to add it in my html:

```
<span>{{username}}</span>
```

Intellisense isn't recognising anything that is setup within my controller (ctrl+space brings up nothing). Is there a setting that can fix this?

Comment: You can use `/// <reference path="xxxxx\xxx.js" />(the path of the js file you want to use)`.

Answer (score 1):

> Intellisense isn't recognising anything that is setup within my
>   controller (ctrl+space brings up nothing). Is there a setting that can
>   fix this?

you can try these two solutions:

**1)** add this on the top of your html file.

```
/// <reference path="xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.js" />(the path of the js file)
```

**2)**  you can also add all js paths which you want to use into a single summary file named `_references.js`.

Right-click on your project--->`Add New Item`-->add a new file named `_references.js`. In this file, you can add these:

```
/// <reference path="xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.js" />(the path of the js file)
/// <reference path=""xxxx\xxx\angular.js />
........
```

**>** you can add any files which you want to use by Intellisense in this `_references.js` file.

**Note**: When you use this way, you do not need to add reference path in the html file bacause this is the **global AngularJS Intellisense**.

**In addition**, if the intellisense of `_references.js` does not work in a very special situation, you have to choose to add this on the top of the main file:

```
/// <reference path=""xxxx\xxx\_references.js />
```

You can refer to [this document](https://madskristensen.net/blog/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) for more detailed info.
Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as of VS 2017, _references.js is no longer supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2019

Comment: Actually, no matter how you called the `_references.js` file in VS2017, if you call it another name, you just add any reference paths into it so that you can  call the content in the whole project.